# How do I create a Crystal Reports Line chart from a cross-tab

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm creating Crystal Report charts through VS 2015 using VB.Net and SQL Server 2008. I created a SP which pretty much brings back all the data I need:

[image]

Using the regular line chart I get:
[image]

This displays the data exactly as I want except for the dates at the bottom which begin with 201810 (stands for Oct '18 and is the beginning of the fiscal year). I formatted the dates with numbers so Crystal wouldn't re-order them.

Using a Cross-tab chart I have been able to convert the numbers to Oct '18, Nov '18, Dec '18, Jan '19, etc.... :

[image]

so when I use the chart they are displayed in the correct order:

[image]

However, with the line chart I am having problems creating an accurate cross-tab for my line chart. How can I use the data from the first image to create a line chart with accurate dates as shown in the fourth image?

Comment: The data in first line graph is correct, but the issue is with date format shown below it?

Comment: Yes, the data is correct and the issue is with the date format below it. As mentioned I successfully formatted the cross-tab with the bar chart but cannot seem to get the correct cross-tab chart (at least I think my problem is the cross-tab) with the line chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out without having to use the Cross-tab. In the stored procedure I simply included the ROW_NUMBER() function and used it in the Order By clause. I also created another column with the formatted date the way it needed to be presented. And in Crystal Reports from the Chart Expert window I chose the formatted field in the For each option. Because I did the order by in the Stored Procedure the data was in the order I wanted it so the formatted date was in the order I needed it on the chart.